# X path is not able to extract element required in spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = AmazonItem()
    item['url'] = response.url
    item['SellerName'] = response.xpath(".//*[@id='bylineInfo']/text()").extract()[0].strip()
    item['itemtitle'] = response.xpath(".//*[@id='productTitle']/text()").extract()[0].strip()
    item['rating'] = response.xpath(".//*[@class='a-icon-alt']/text()").extract()[0].strip()
    item['price'] = response.xpath(".//*[@class='a-size-medium a-color-price']/text()").extract()[0].strip()
    try:
        list = response.xpath(".//*[@class='a-unordered-list a-vertical a-spacing-none']/li/span[@class='a-list-item']/text()").extract()
        item['desc'] = [s.strip() for s in list]
    except IndexError:
        item['desc']="No Description"
```

In the above code i am trying to fetch price,title,reviews and the description if present,It extracts everything for a link where description is present but does not write anything for a link where thereis no description can any one help. follwing are the links :
[https://www.amazon.com/Angelkiss-Leather-shoulder-backpack-K15631/dp/B01NCX988Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NCX988Q) --- with description
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B06W9HL2L1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06W9HL2L1) --- without description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to avoid using compound classes. I've tried to show how they should be defined. All you need to do is replace the xapths used below with the one you have used in your scrapy project.

```
import requests
from scrapy import Selector

url = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01NCX988Q/?tag=stackoverflow17-20"

res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
sel = Selector(res)
product_url = res.url
seller = sel.xpath("//a[@id='bylineInfo']/text()").extract_first()
title = sel.xpath("//*[@id='productTitle']/text()").extract_first().strip()
rating = sel.xpath("//span[@class='a-icon-alt']/text()").extract_first().strip()
price = sel.xpath("//*[@id='priceblock_ourprice']/text()").extract_first().strip()
desc = [' '.join(item.split()) for item in sel.xpath("//*[@id='feature-bullets']//*[@class='a-list-item']/text()").extract()]
print(f'{product_url}\n{seller}\n{title}\n{rating}\n{price}\n{desc}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't start with "." for xpath expressions. It is for realative xpath expressions.

```
from operator import methodcaller

if response.css('span.a-list-item::text'):
    item['description'] = filter(bool, map(methodcaller('strip'), response.css('span.a-list-item::text').extract()))
else:
    item['description'] = 'No Description'
```

Answer (score 0):

The item you gave without description happens to be out of stock and its totally different with the scenario of not having a description.
And following current examples you give when an item is out of stock these attributes never comes. :) so first check for the availability of the product then go for its attributes.